# how to bind response data in angular using http Client using thrid party api

Tags: angular

how to bind response data in angular using http Client using thrid party api.

get response data show in console but not able to bind **train route data** in my UI.
[image]

I have uploaded my code to github. please have a look of my code.
https://github.com/vibhutikumar11/angularHttpClientGetRequest/

Thanks

Comment: You havent written any code in https://github.com/vibhutikumar11/angularHttpClientGetRequest/blob/master/src/app/app.component.html. How are you trying to bind ?

Comment: this is my component ts file.
https://github.com/vibhutikumar11/angularHttpClientGetRequest/blob/master/src/app/app.component.ts

please have a look . actually i do not know how to declare nested interface.you can see attached screen shot of my console. stucked to bind train route data to my html.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[Check this example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5t8ufs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

you simply need to assign a variable

```
  ngOnInit() { 
    this.http.get<DataResponse>('https://api.railwayapi.com/v2/route/train/12566/apikey/xg6ymuliox/').subscribe(data => {
         this.data = data;
        },
        (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          if (err.error instanceof Error) {
            console.log('Client-side error occured.');
          } else {
            console.log('Server-side error occured.');
          }
        }
      );
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. your solution works for me.
now  i am able to bind data like this in my html.
Thanks.

<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>#</th>
    <th>station Name</th>
    <th>Arr</th>
    <th>Dep</th>
    <th>Halt</th>
    <th>Dist</th>
    <th>Day</th>
    <th>PF</th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let route of data.route">
    <td></td>
    <td>{{route.station.name}}</td>
    <td>{{route.scharr}}</td>
    <td>{{route.schdep}}</td>
    <td>{{route.halt}}</td>
    <td>{{route.distance}}</td>
    <td>{{route.day}}</td>
    <td>{{route.no}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>

Comment: @vibhutiKumar . Please mark it as answer as well ;) .

Answer (score 0):

You can use async observables to bind the data from api directly to angular component.

In .ts

```
 myObservable = new Observable((observer) => {
  this.http.get<DataResponse>('https://api.railwayapi.com/v2/route/train/12566/apikey/xg6ymuliox/').subscribe(data => {
    observer.next(data);

         },
         (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
           if (err.error instanceof Error) {
             console.log('Client-side error occured.');
           } else {
             console.log('Server-side error occured.');
           }
         }
       );
      }
      );
```

In .html

```
<div *ngFor="let item of myObservable | async">
     Do any bindings you want
 </div>
```